# How can i set the BackColor of ToolStripContainer to gradient color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a ToolStripContainer on a winform. I want to set the BackColor of its ContentPanel to custom gradient color.

How can I set it?

Comment: first show us what you have tried?

Comment: I don't undestand what you say. I can set the BackColor of any control (specially ToolStripContainer.ContentPanel) to a solid color like Color.White or Color.FromArgb(,,). But I want to set it by a gradient color for example the gradient seen on the toolbar of office programs.

Comment: @HamidReza Please show your code. How did you try to solve the issue yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple class that inherits from `ToolStripContainer` and set up `BackgroundImage` (or anything else) in the its constructor. For example:

```
class MyToolStripContainer : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContainer
{
    public MyToolStripContainer()
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Height, rect.Width))
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
            rect,
            Color.Blue,
            Color.Red,
            LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal))
        {
            brush.SetSigmaBellShape(0.5f);
            graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            ContentPanel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromHbitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap());
        }
        ContentPanel.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only `ToolStripContentPanel`, no `winform` controls supports `"Gradient colors"` out of the box, but they provide a way to custom painting. That's how we can accomplish the gradient `look and feel` in `winforms`.

```
toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Paint += ContentPanel_Paint;//Triggering up the paint event

public void ContentPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripContentPanel panel = (ToolStripContentPanel)sender;
    using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(panel.ClientRectangle, Color.Gray, Color.Red, 90))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, panel.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```